# Как остановить выполнение функции? (котлин, андроид)

Tags: android, kotlin

Логика выполнения программы:

```
fun function1 {
        alertDateBeforeAll()
        function3()    
        function4()
        <какой-то код>
}
```

function2(), function3(), function4() - это функции поверки на условия. При не соблюдении какого-то условия в какой-то из функций выводится алерт и программа должна остановиться.

Как в условиях этих функций указать прервать работу кода, если условие не выполняется (или выполняется)?

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun FirstFragment.alertDateBeforeAll() {
    if (dataIsk.isBefore(dataStartSid) || dataIsk.isBefore(dataString3parse) || dataIsk.isBefore(dataString4parse) || dataString3parse.isBefore(dataStartSid) || dataString4parse.isBefore(dataStartSid) || dataString4parse.isBefore(dataString3parse)) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        with(dialogBuilder) {
            setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
            setTitle("Проверьте даты!")
            setMessage("Нарушена последовательность введенных дат!")
            setCancelable(false)
            setNegativeButton("Ок", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { 
               dialogAlert, id ->
            })
            show()
        }
        return
    }
}
```

return не работает, вот [пример](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjIxIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBjaGVja0FnZShhZ2U6IEludCl7XG4gICAgaWYoYWdlIDwgMCB8fCBhZ2UgPiAxMTApe1xuICAgICAgICBwcmludGxuKFwiSW52YWxpZCBhZ2VcIilcbiAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuXG4gICAgfVxuICAgIHByaW50bG4oXCJBZ2UgaXMgdmFsaWRcIilcbn1cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuIFxuICAgIGNoZWNrQWdlKC0xMClcbiAgICBjaGVja0FnZSgxMClcbn0iLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6ImphdmEiLCJhcmdzIjoiIn0=)

Comment: Ну и проверять - если из функции пришел алерт, то останавливать.

Comment: [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200)

Comment: надо не "убить" программу, а просто остановить. Чтобы пользователь вернулся к вводу правильных данных.

Comment: @Эникейщик подскажите как?

Comment: Вам ключевое слово `return` известно? Ставите его в любое место, где надо "остановить" функцию и она прекращает работу.

Comment: в моем случае почему то не прекращает (логика кода: проверяется условие, если истина - выводится алерт об ошибке и потом return. Но код продолжается выполняться и выполняется следующая функция проверки), если бы так работало - не писал бы вопрос с приложением большого количества разборов ситуации

Comment: вот тут про return сказано, но не знаю как его применить   https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/returns.html/ Может дело в то что, что для выхода из лямбды нам нужно использовать label? Добавил код функции в вопрос

Comment: Если дошли до `return` (без лейблов), то вышли из функции, других вариантов нет. Распечатайте что-нибудь в лог прямо перед `return`, чтобы проверить, дошли вы до него или нет.

Comment: если надо прервать всю цепочку выполнения функций по определенным условиям и не ставить везде проверки по коду, можно использовать корутины и просто отменять ее, когда это необходимо. Таким образом вы прервем все выполнение кода.

Comment: function2(), function3(), function4() - это функции поверки на условия - и как они работают? они должны возвращать булёвый результат и тогда нужно писать `if(function2()) return`

Comment: @DrMcSheen в тексте вопроса приведен код основной функции и код функции проверки. Если кратко: alertDateBeforeAll(), function3(), function4() - это функции поверки на условия. При не соблюдении какого-то условия в какой-то из функций выводится алерт и программа должна остановиться. Как бы возвращать в основную function1() они ничего не должны, хотя можно сделать возврат true

Comment: @Vadik вышли из функции № 2 - alertDateBeforeAll() , но её задача вывести алерт и остановить function1().  Сама т она может и останавливается, но затем код  function1() продолжает выполняться

Comment: @Pentiux подскажите как здесь использовать корутины

Comment: так что ли нужно сделать?  `public var test = false...... В alertDateBeforeAll() /условие/..... test = true..... в function1() ..... if  test = false ....../дальнейшее выполнение/....`

Comment: @jurvrn типа такого https://pl.kotl.in/IqQ6kw99A

Comment: спасибо, вроде понятно.... а проще нельзя? ) как пример - вернуть true из alertDateBeforeAll(), проверить это в function1 и не выполнять дальше function1 если не true ?

Comment: я не знаю нужной логики, просто если присутствует множественные условия и они распределены по разным функция, а логика требует прекратить все дальнейшее выполнение кода по любым из условий, то корутины хорошо поднходят. Можно возвращать значения, а ниже по стэку делать проверки и тд, но когда вызовов много и есть варианты, самй простой способ остановить выполнение - корутины, имхо. А так все сильно зависит от вашей логики.

Comment: да просто приложение то вроде примитивное - сравнение и анализ дат, а корутины это что-то серьезное. Поэтому и спросил так. Но в то же время проверок много и они важны. Значит и корутины могу использовать. А если возвращать значение то записать это как? Создаем переменную - `public var alert= false` ...... В alertDateBeforeAll() /если условие выполнено переменной присваиваем  true/..... `alert= true` ..... В function1() ставим дальнейшее выполнение кода в зависимости от значения переменной alert- `if  alert = false` /если false то идет дальнейшее выполнение function1()/

Comment: А в чём проблема в проверочной функции сделать, если выводится alert, возвращать `return true`, если нет - `return false`. А в основной функции - `if(function2()) return`

Comment: Так даже короче решение, но я ещё не разобрался - как отследить вывод alert'a...? с другой стороны дело ведь не в алерте, а в непрохождении проверки на условие...